# Starting a Pig server in mapreduce mode, within java

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to run a Pig command from a java program. I'd like Pig to run in MapReduce mode on a distant hadoop cluster.
This is the way I initialize my PigServer:

```
Properties configuration = new Properties();
PropertiesUtil.loadPropertiesFromFile(configuration, CONF_FILE);

configuration.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", properties.getProperty(mapredJT_property, mapredJobTracker));
configuration.setProperty("fs.default.name", properties.getProperty(hdfsURI_property, fsDefaultName));

PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, configuration);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 4010: Cannot find hadoop configurations in classpath (neither hadoop-site.xml nor core-site.xml was found in the classpath). If you plan to use local mode, please put -x local option in command line
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:162)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:122)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:301)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:220)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:197)
    at com.mycompany.testpig.idmapreduce.toto(idmapreduce.java:68)
    at com.mycompany.testpig.idmapreduce.main(idmapreduce.java:46)
```

I can't find a way to give the hadoop-site.xml and core-site.xml files to Pig so it starts the server correctly. I've been trying to setup the variables as described [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/start.html#Running+the+Pig+Scripts+in+Mapreduce+Mode), with no results. I'm using maven and netbeans to run/test my program.
I also tried to put the 2 files in the root of my project (next to src/), it didn't work.

Let me know if you have a solution!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to work around the issue, by simply putting an empty core-site.xml in src/main/resources. Maven copies it in target/classes when compiling so it is automatically in the classpath when I run the program.

Hope it helps somebody else.

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same exception while running Pig from Java. This has been resolved after adding path of hadoop conf directory to the project property libraries add jar/folder

Ref: http://helpmetocode.blogspot.in/2012/04/exception-in-thread-main.html

Thanks,

Kalai